# Woocommerce Update weight and attribute programmatically using custom field

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have been struggling with this for some time and cannot work out what is wrong or find the answer online.

I have a custom field for pack size on my products. If I enter a value here I have added a function that works out the m2 price using that field and the price and updated another field automatically. This works great.

The problem is that I also want it to update the products weight and an attribute and I cannot get that to work. Here is the code I am using

```
    add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id)
{
    $woocommerce_custom_product_number_field = $_POST['_product_pack_size'];
    $product_price = $_POST['_regular_price'];
    $woocommerce_sqm_price_field = round($product_price / $woocommerce_custom_product_number_field,2); 
    $woocommerce_sqm_price_field_r = round($product_price / $woocommerce_custom_product_number_field); 
    if( !empty ($woocommerce_custom_product_number_field) ) {   

        update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_pack_size', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_number_field));
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', esc_attr($woocommerce_sqm_price_field) );
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_sqm_price', esc_attr($woocommerce_sqm_price_field));
        wp_set_object_terms( $productID, esc_attr($woocommerce_sqm_price_field_r), 'pa_price-per-m2', true );
        $att_sqm = Array('pa_price-per-m2' =>Array(
            'name'=>'pa_price-per-m2',
            'value'=> esc_attr($woocommerce_sqm_price_field_r),
            'is_visible' => '1',
            'is_taxonomy' => '1'
        ));
        update_post_meta( $productID, '_product_attributes', $att_sqm);

    } 
        
}
```

The weight does not update at all. If it does not already exist the attribute is correctly created but the product is not associated with it.

I am sure it is something small and stupid that I have missed. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Note: use [`woocommerce_admin_process_product_object`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3377c60c5e5602a4c82b6ef43b7b48b9c895f9ad/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php#L418) to save instead of the outdated `woocommerce_process_product_meta` hook. 
It also seems more dynamic to update other fields when entering a value in your custom field via jQuery instead of overwriting the values ​​while saving. The adjusted values ​​(other fields, updated with jQuery) will then be automatically saved, when the save button is hit to save the value from your custom field